# Run all my doctests for all python modules in a folder without seeing failures because of bad imports

Tags: python, testing, doctest

I've started integrating doctests into my modules.  (Hooray!)  These tend to be files which started as scripts, and are now are a few functions with CLI apps in the `__name__=='__main__'`, so I don't want to put the running of the tests there.  I tried `nosetests --with-doctest`, but get lots of failures I don't want to see, because during test discovery this import modules which don't contain doctests but do require importing things I don't have installed on this system, or should be run within special python installations. Is there a way I can run just all of my doctests?

I've considered a hotkey in vim to run "import doctest; doctest.testfile(currentFilename)" to run my doctests in the current module, and another script that runs all the tests - what do other doctest users do?  Or should I be using something other than doctest?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think [nose](http://packages.python.org/nose/) is the way. You should either exclude the problematic modules explicitly with `-e` or catch the missing imports in your code with constructs like this:

```
try:
    import simplejson as json
except ImportError:
    import json
```

**Update:**

Another option is to provide mock replacements for the missing modules. Let's say your code has something like this:

```
import myfunkymodule
```

and you're trying run your tests in a system where `myfunkymodule` is missing. You could create a `mock_modules/myfunkymodule.py` file with mock implementations of the stuff you need from it (perhaps using [MiniMock](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/MiniMock), which I highly recommend if you are using [doctest](http://docs.python.org/library/doctest.html)). You could then run `nose` like this:

```
$ PYTHONPATH=path_to/mock_modules nosetests --with-doctest
```

Comment: I'm having trouble using -e to exclude even looking for the doctests, in certain modules, which is when the import statements are encountered.  How is -e normally used?  The regex to exclude the tests apparently can't just be the module name.

Comment: True, `-e` won't help in your case. Still, `nosetests` is the way for test discovery in python AFAIK. You should go for the `try/except ImportError` approach, or else provide mock implementations for your missing modules somewhere in your `PYTHONPATH` (see my last edit).

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into this.  I may end up hacking a script that greps for the `>>>` interactive prompt inside of a docstring, and just runs `doctest.testfile(file)` on those modules instead.  But for a more complete testing solution, what you suggest sounds better.

Answer (score 6):

You can also create unittests that wrap desired doctests modules, it is a native feature of doctests: http://docs.python.org/2/library/doctest.html#unittest-api.

```python
import unittest
import doctest 
import my_module_with_doctests

def load_tests(loader, tests, ignore):
    tests.addTests(doctest.DocTestSuite(my_module_with_doctests))
    return tests
```

Comment: You can also pass in a string rather than a module, ie. `doctest.DocTestSuite("my_module_with_doctests")`